# Flume Tail a File

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am new to Flume-Ng and need help to tail a file. I have a cluster running hadoop with flume running remotely. I communicate to this cluster by using putty. I want to tail a file on my PC and put it on the HDFS in the cluster. I am using the following code to this.

```
#flume.conf: http source, hdfs sink
# Name the components on this agent 

tier1.sources = r1
tier1.sinks = k1
tier1.channels = c1


# Describe/configure the source
tier1.sources.r1.type = exec
tier1.sources.r1.command = tail -F /(Path to file on my PC)


# Describe the sink
tier1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
tier1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/ntimbadi/flume/
tier1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
tier1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
tier1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
tier1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute



 # Use a channel which buffers events in memory
 tier1.channels.c1.type = memory
 tier1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
 tier1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100


 # Bind the source and sink to the channel
 tier1.sources.r1.channels = c1
 tier1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I believe the mistake is in the source. This kind source does not take the host name or i.p to look for(in this case should be my PC). Could someone just give me a hint as to how to tail a file on my PC to upload it to the remotely located HDFS using flume.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` source in your configuration will run on the machine where you start the flume's `tier1` agent. If you want to collect data from another machine, you'll need to start a flume agent on that machine too; to sum up you need:

- an agent (`remote1`) running on the remote machine that has an `avro` source, which will listen for events from collector agents and will act like an aggregator.
- an agent (`local1`) running on **your** machine (to act like a collector) that has an `exec` source and sends data to the remote agent via `avro` sink.

Or alternatively, you can have only one flume agent running on your local machine (having the same configuration you posted) and set the hdfs path as "hdfs://REMOTE_IP/hdfs/path" (though I'm not entirely sure this will work).

edit: 
Below are the sample configurations for the 2-agents scenario (they may not work without some modification).

```
remote1.channels.mem-ch-1.type = memory

remote1.sources.avro-src-1.channels = mem-ch-1
remote1.sources.avro-src-1.type = avro
remote1.sources.avro-src-1.port = 10060
remote1.sources.avro-src-1.bind = 10.88.66.4 /* REPLACE WITH YOUR MACHINE'S EXTERNAL IP */

remote1.sinks.k1.channel = mem-ch-1
remote1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
remote1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/ntimbadi/flume/
remote1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
remote1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
remote1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
remote1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

remote1.sources = avro-src-1
remote1.sinks = k1
remote1.channels = mem-ch-1
```

and

```
local1.channels.mem-ch-1.type = memory

local1.sources.exc-src-1.channels = mem-ch-1
local1.sources.exc-src-1.type = exec
local1.sources.exc-src-1.command = tail -F /(Path to file on my PC)

local1.sinks.avro-snk-1.channel = mem-ch-1
local1.sinks.avro-snk-1.type = avro
local1.sinks.avro-snk-1.hostname = 10.88.66.4 /* REPLACE WITH REMOTE IP */
local1.sinks.avro-snk-1.port = 10060

local1.sources = exc-src-1
local1.sinks = avro-snk-1
local1.channels = mem-ch-1
```

Comment: Sir I am using Flume-Ng and not Flume-oG.

Comment: I know, I meant `collector` and `aggregator`as names for your agents, you can just as well call them `agent1` and `agent2`...

Comment: Cihat thanks for your help. Do you have any links or any sample for the code. Also to explain you the real situation I am accessing a cluster of 8 machines via a gateway server with flume agent running on each machine in the cluster. I wanted to ask on what machine should my source file be? Caz righnow its on the gateway server.

Comment: See the edited answer for configuration sample. About the 8 machine cluster thing, you should add more info about your cluster in the question if you need help about it too. You may want to use something like [load balancing sink processor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#load-balancing-sink-processor) as explained in the flume user guide.